# Replacement for the sit-for function

Tags: process

Using currently the `sit-for` function, every time i hit any key and cause user input the sit-for will stop. Is there any possibility to have something like sit-for, while being able to move the cursor around an typing and not causing any break of the process in run (with sleeping time intervals in it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to, after a certain amount of time, run some code?

You can use a [timer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html). In the simplest way of using it, you can pass it a number of seconds to wait, tell it not to repeat, then give it a lambda to run. For example:

```
(run-at-time 1     ;; in one second
             nil   ;; do NOT repeat
             (lambda ()    ;; this lambda is called
                     (message "I ran!")))
```

This will, in one second, call the lambda `(lambda () (message "I ran!"))`. Replace the body of this lambda with the code you want to run.